# How to recover missing SKPaymentTransactions?

Tags: ios, storekit

I have one test account that has exactly two purchases in its transaction history.  Both products are Non-Consumable.

I logged in on iPad 1 and bought product A.

Then I logged out of iPad 1 and logged in on iPad 2 and bought product B.

Then I attempted to restore previous transactions using `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];` to unlock product A on iPad 2.

When the call comes back, only product B is in the list of restorable transactions.

Additionally, when I attempt to buy product A again on iPad 2 using

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:productA];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

I get a popup saying 'You've already purchased this.  Tap OK to download it again for free.'

If I've already purchased product A, why isn't it in the list of products when I try to restore previous purchases?  Why do I have to have the user attempt to purchase it again?

EDIT:
I've discovered that it doesn't matter which iPad I use (iPad 1 or iPad 2), only product B shows up in the list of restorable transactions and product A needs to be repurchased.

EDIT:
I extrapolated the product request, restore and purchase work into its own project with the same bundle ID and product IDs as the original.

Now *nothing* appears in the list of restorable transactions but the same popup appears when I attempt to buy either product.

Another trip down the rabbit hole with broken Apple tools.

EDIT:
The inspiration for this investigation is a rash of user complaints about missing entitlements.  This largely started to become an issue when users were switching from their iPad 2s to new iPad 3s.  This isn't consistent among all my users, but enough of them have raised a stink about it to make it a priority, and Apple customer support has directed them back to me, but I'm not sure this is a problem I can fix, especially since Apple insists on being the cash register for in-app purchasing.

Comment: I'm also wondering if this is the normal behaviour, it behaves the same for me.

Comment: This can't be normal.  An user's entire transaction history should be available on any device at any time.

Comment: I am having this problem in iOS 7. The restore button will fail, but if the user tries to purchase again, it will say that they have already purchased the item and ask if they want to download it. How did you go about solving this in the end?

Comment: @JPK I didn't.  The problem disappeared for some users and appeared for some others.  It seems to be a crapshoot.  The best I can tell you is to make sure you're storing entitlements remotely, on your own servers, and having your users log in to your services.  Apple's proven untrustworthy in this regard, with multiple DTS tickets and bug reports unanswered or unresolved for over two years, collectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it on good authority that this is a bug in Apple's server software somewhere.

Comment: I see this problem all the time, especially with test itunes accounts. Problem still exists in iOS 7 GM.

Answer (score 3):

This message  'You've already purchased this. Tap OK to download it again for free.' is usually appear when you add a payment transaction to the default queue and didn't finish the transaction so the `StoreKit` suppose that the user did purchased the item but it hasn't been downloaded by your application , so make sure that you are delivered the item to the user and finish the transaction ... I'v got a way to retrieve the user purchased items and its work good for me .. try it

```
- (void) checkPurchasedItems
{
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}//You Call This Function

//Then this delegate Function Will be fired
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
  purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
  for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
  {
      NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
      [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
  }

}
```

the `purchasedItemIDs` will contain all the product IDs that the user purchased it.

Comment: Yes, I do this. The `queue` parameter in this callback is just as empty as the transaction observer callback.

Comment: You don't get called back for all products that should be restored sometimes. This is still a bug in iOS 7 GM.